# Azure Template reference function does not work for existing resource (not in template)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

trying to use reference function in my ARM template for a resource that is already existing, but not included in my template. This does not seem to work.  Is there some way to do this?

In particular, I'm deploy a new SQL database to an existing SQL server, along with a new webapp.  In the web app, I'm trying to set connection string using

```
reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlserverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName
```

but this doesnot work - says the resource is not available/included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference function to work on existing resources you need to pass in the API versión. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource?toc=%2fazure%2ftemplates%2ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Ftemplates%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#reference).

apiVersion - API version of the specified resource. Include this parameter when the resource is not provisioned within same template. Typically, in the format, yyyy-mm-dd.

```
reference(parameters('storageAccountName'), '2016-12-01')
```

Comment: If the existing resources is not in the same resourceGroup, you also need to add the resourceGroup parameter to the fn - as mentioned in the docs.